# Turning microposts into hyperlinks with Rinku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, railstutorial.org

I am having trouble getting Rinku to work correctly, i.e. turn my microposts into hyperlinks. I have installed Rinku

gem 'rinku'
created a helper for microposts at app/helpers/micropost_helper.erb

```
require 'rinku'

module MicroPostHelper
  def add_links(text)
    Rinku.auto_link(feed_item.content)
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure what to do with the (text) openings. I know feed_item.content goes in there somewhere. Here is my _feed_item.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Can someone please walk me through how to get this working? I don't know how to wrap line 6 of _feed_item.html.erb in the Rinku code, or how to get the helper to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used rinku, but it looks like you've defined a regular old ruby method in your helper. This is a method just like `time_ago_in_words` is-- so you can call the method and pass your `feed_item.content` as the argument.

That would look like:

```
<span class="content"><%= add_links(feed_item.content) %></span>
```

Does that do what you expect it to do?

EDIT: Oh, I see something else: in your `add_links` method definition, since you're going to be passing in `feed_item.content` as an argument that becomes `text` in the method, you need to use that in your method:

```
  def add_links(text)
    Rinku.auto_link(text)
  end
```

Does that make sense?